# Can't display image on Image View in android through socket

Tags: java, android, image, sockets, screenshot

I'm trying to take a screenshot from server  using Robot class then send it to android and then display the screenshot on Image view widget.

this my server code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
     try {
      ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(400);
      System.out.println("Running.....");
      while (true) {
       Socket serverSockt = server.accept();
       System.out.println("Accept.....");

       Toolkit toolKit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
       Dimension dimension = toolKit.getScreenSize();
       Robot robot = new Robot();
       BufferedImage screenshot = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(dimension));
       ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(screenshot);

       ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(serverSockt.getOutputStream());
       oos.writeObject(icon);
       oos.flush();
       oos.close();

       serverSockt.close();
      }
     } catch (IOException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(VNCserver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     } catch (AWTException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(VNCserver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
    }
   });
   t.start();
  }
```

and this client code(android):

```
btnConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
       Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {


        @Override
        public void run() {
         try {
          Socket clinetSocket = new Socket(txtIP.getText().toString(), Integer.parseInt(txtPort.getText().toString()))

          ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(clinetSocket.getInputStream());

          byte[] buffer = (byte[]) ois.readObject();
          img = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
          viwe.setImageBitmap(img);

          clinetSocket.close();

         } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
         }
        }
       });
       th.start();
      }
     });
```

I don't know where it goes wrong ?, and i'm not getting IOException error, My first thought is maybe my client is receiving empty input stream. Any help ? What is the mistake I have done ? if my whole code is wrong .. then how I can make server to take a screenshot then send it to android client and display the screenshot whether in image view or Canvas.

Comment: Your code does not look bad. But you are trying to make a bitmap from the received object. But the received object is an ImageIcon. So the question is can that be done?  You should first investigate if the received object is indeed equal to the sent object. How many bytes were sent? How many bytes are received in your buffer? Your bitmap will have a null value now i think.

Comment: `serverSockt.close();`. Put that below the while loop. At the moment the server can handle only one client and will crash then.

Comment: My god.. Im wrong. Why did you call a client socket a server socket?
 Name it client socket. And then you can leave it as last statement.

Comment: I'm not a programmer .. hmm  if don't mind , can u please tell how to solve things out. I mean how to turn what u have said into a code ? :|

Comment: I asked how many bytes were sent and how many received. You should find out and tell.